# Retrieve image from firebase in android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i retrieve images from **firebase** . i am converting my images to **base64** string first then saving it to **firebase** string code below.

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
byte[] byteArray =  baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBytes(byteArray,Base64.ENCODE);

ref.push().setValue(encodedImage);
```

Now how can i show this image in my activity.

Comment: use DecompressFormat after getting the image .......

Comment: Could you please explain with a code  as i am newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] decodeImage = Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.ENCODE);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodeImage);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I am getting error on using above code cannot resolve method 'decodeByteArray(byte[])' .

Comment: For retrieving images i am using                 `byte[]    dec = Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.ENCODE);          Bitmap decodeByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dec,0,dec.length);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeByte);  `